# scraping data using Watir no longer loading JSON dynamic content from a website

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nokogiri, watir

I've been using watir to scrape data from nfl.com for over a year and it suddenly stopped working. It appears that it's a timing issue and is loading the site before the json data is finished loading the dynamic content. I'm pretty sure it's something in the way I'm trying to load the website but I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days with no answers.

Here is my relevant Gemfile.lock info:

```
nokogiri (1.13.9)
  mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.0)
  racc (~> 1.4)
watir (7.1.0)
  regexp_parser (>= 1.2, < 3)
  selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
web-console (3.7.0)
  actionview (>= 5.0)
  activemodel (>= 5.0)
  bindex (>= 0.4.0)
  railties (>= 5.0)
webdrivers (5.2.0)
  nokogiri (~> 1.6)
  rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
  selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
selenium-webdriver (4.5.0)
  childprocess (>= 0.5, < 5.0)
  rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
  rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
  websocket (~> 1.0)
```

Chrome driver version is

```
ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.212 (e3cd97fc771b893b7fd1879196d1215b622c2bed-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#1429})
```

Here is the code I'm using to call watir and nokogiri:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  args = ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-gpu',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222']
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true, options: {args: args}
else
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
end
url_path = "http://www.nfl.com/schedules/" + year + "/REG" + weekNum.to_s
browser.goto(url_path)
js_doc = browser.main(id: "main-content").wait_until(&:present?)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(js_doc.inner_html)
```

And here is an example on how I'm parsing the nokogiri data, which is always returning blank right now. It used to work.:

```
game_date = game_group.css('h2.d3-o-section-title').text
```

And finally here is the HTML you get when doing an inspect from inside Chrome. The HTML I care about comes after the .

```
<main role="main" id="main-content" tabindex="0" aria-label="Page main content">
  <section class="d3-l-section-row d3-l-section-row--no-margin-top">... </section>
  <section class="d3-l-section-row">...</section>
  <section class="d3-l-grid--outer d3-l-section-row">...</section>
  <section class="d3-l-grid--outer d3-l-adv-row">...</section>

  <div data-json-module="{";Name";:";Schedules";,";Module";:{";seasonFromUrl";:2022,";SeasonType";:";REG9";,";WeekFromUrl";:9,";HeaderCountryCode";:";US";,";TimeZoneID";:";America/Chicago";,";PreSeasonPlacement";:0,";RegularSeasonPlacement";:0,";PostSeasonPlacement";:0}}" data-require="modules/scheduleByWeek" data-require-loaded="true">

    <span style="display:none">...</span>
    <section class="d3-l-grid--outer d3-l-section-row nfl-o-matchup-group">
      <div class="d3-l-grid--inner">
        <div class="d3-l-col__col-12">
            <h2 class="d3-o-section-title">Thursday, November 3rd</h2>
          <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip nfl-c-matchup-strip--post-game">
           <a class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__left-area" href="/games/eagles-at-texans-2022-reg-9" aria-label="Texans vs Eagles game page">
            <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__game-info">
            <p class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__period">FINAL</p>
          </div>
          <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__game">
            <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team nfl-c-matchup-strip__team--opponent">
            <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-score" data-require="modules/displayScores" data-score="29" data-require-loaded="true">29</div>
              <p class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-name">
                <span class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-logo">
                  <picture>... </picture>
                </span>
                <span class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-abbreviation"> PHI </span>
                <span class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-fullname"> Eagles </span>
              </p>
              <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__record">(8-0)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-separator">
              <span class="nfl-o-icon nfl-o-icon--medium">... </span>
            </div>
            <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team">
              <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-score" data-require="modules/displayScores" data-score="17" data-require-loaded="true">17</div>
                <p class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-name">
                  <span class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-logo">...</span>
                  <span class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-abbreviation"> HOU </span>
                  <span class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__team-fullname"> Texans </span>
                </p>
                <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__record">(1-6-1)</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="nfl-c-matchup-strip__right-area">
            <a class="nfl-o-cta nfl-o-cta--link" href="/games/eagles-at-texans-2022-reg-9" aria-label="Replay">
              <span class="nfl-o-icon nfl-o-icon--medium">...</span>
              <span>Replay</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

For the past year, waiting for the main content to load using "js_doc = browser.main(id: "main-content").wait_until(&:present?)" but it appears that is returning too soon.  I've tried waiting on content after the data-json-module div "js_doc = browser.div(class: "nfl-o-matchup-group")" but it always times out.  And I'm not sure how to key on .

I'm really not sure why it worked for so long and is now breaking.  However, I'm guessing I'm keying on the wrong things and causing this race condition but I don't know what else to try.  I'm hoping someone with a little more watir knowledge can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

When I load the page with a slower internet connection:

- `browser.main(id: "main-content")` starts present and
- There is a spinner, `browser.div(class: 'nfl-o-spinner')`, present before the actual game data appears.

I would try waiting for either:

- Game data to appear - `browser.section(class: 'nfl-o-matchup-group')` or
- No game data to be found - `browser.section(class: 'nfl-o-no-results')`

So the loading of the page would become:

```
browser.goto(url_path)
browser.wait_until(timeout: 120) { browser.section(class: 'nfl-o-matchup-group').present? || browser.section(class: 'nfl-o-no-results').present? }
js_doc = browser.main(id: 'main-content')
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(js_doc.inner_html)
```

Comment: I tried your answer but all of the data still isn't loaded and the div.nfl-o-spinner is still present.  Is there a way to wait until that is not present?  That seems like what I might need to try

Comment: I tried this multiple times and I always get this error - "Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on #<Watir::Browser:0x..fe3d6ceb43fa87800 url="https://www.nfl.com/schedules/2022/reg1/" title="NFL 2022 - WEEK 1 Schedule | NFL.com">"

Comment: If you manually go to the page, does it take longer than 30 seconds to load the game data? Given the spinner is still displayed, try increasing the `:timeout` so the data has more time to load - I updated the answer to include a 2 minute wait. If you want to try waiting for the spinner to disappear, you can do `browser.div(class: 'nfl-o-spinner').wait_while(&:present?)`, but I don't find that approach to be as robust.

Comment: I finally had time to try this out again and it appears there is something else going on besides waiting for the page to load.  If I load it through Chrome directly it loads fairly quickly.  If I try to load it through watir, using selenium and headless Chrome it never loads.  Even 120 seconds is not long enough.  I'm not sure what to look at but I'm going to try updating everything regarding selenium and chromium.